# REST: Can not see items in a list

Tags: office-365, rest

So I tried to the get the contents of a list using REST

```
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/tsm/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘OnSite Visits')
```

but I get the following error:

[image]

Not sure what is wrong?

Comment: One of your `'` seems to be wrong, but it could be just a typo?

Comment: You can also take a look into some REST Calls examples here from Atish to get a good start: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Answer (score 4):

One of your `'` seems to be wrong

Change

```
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/tsm/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘OnSite Visits')
```

To

```
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/tsm/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OnSite Visits')
```